# Change look option is missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

Lately I’ve installed on prem or (on local server) 2019 SharePoint server it’s worked therefore I created my site ( communication template).
When I tried to edit the site look there is some options are missing like when i enter “change look” the option of navigation , header and footer not showing at all even when I’m the site owner

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean "change the look" in site settings?